# Whats the difference between gradle and gradle-experimental?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I know that new versions both support NDK for android applications.
But many plugins doesnt work with gradle-experimental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What is gradle?](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Introduction)

> Gradle is an advanced build system as well as an advanced build toolkit allowing to create custom build logic through plugins.

[What is gradle-experimental?](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Introduction)

> The new experimental plugin is based on Gradle’s new component model mechanism, which allows significant reduction in configuration time. It also includes NDK integration for building JNI applications. This user guides provides details on how to use it and highlights the difference between the new plugin and the original plugin.
>
> **WARNING**: Note that this is plugin is at the experimental stage. The Gradle API for the new component model is not final, which means it’ll only work with a specific version of Gradle until the APIs are final.
>
> Additionally, the DSL is likely change significantly, as APIs to create the DSL are finalized.
>
> This is a very early preview of the plugin for feedback on performance and NDK integration.

Essentially, gradle-experimental is a work in progress (as stated above **this plugin is at the experimental stage**) of what gradle itself should become in the future.

---

An analogy:
A house was built some years ago and has been through alot of improvement. Everything is in place, and it appears done. Today, it is a place where you know you'll be safe if you live in it.

Another house is being built at this very moment, because the owners of the house above have plans to move. Some rooms have been constructed, some haven't. Some doors and windows are already in place, some have not even been ordered yet. Some areas they don't even know yet what they are going to do with. Some rooms might appear done, but they may very well be refurnished at any point in time. The ceiling may collapse, the floor may disappear, you'd only know about it when it has already happened. This house is not currently safe to live in.

Gradle is the first house.
Gradle-experimental is the second house.

---

I don't think there is much use in comparing them at this stage. If you don't absolutely need to use gradle-experimental for whatever reason, just stick with the current and stable gradle.

Comment: I am trying to use native code in my app. And i do it like on google-sample-ndk repository. Also i want to use crashlytics. But it incompatible with experimental plugin. So i guess i must switch to stable gradle.

Comment: @ВалентинБарышев gradle experimental is merely a preview of what they are working on atm. You should always use the stable current gradle if you can.